# Testing for mederation effect in a paired sample (before and after)

Tags: t-test, interaction, categorical-encoding, paired-data

I am trying to test whether Covid-19 impacts the income of companies. For 10 companies, I have the income values for both December 2019 (before COVID) and March 2020 (During COVID). I also have the size of the companies for these two dates.

I have already run a paired sample t-test. Now, I want to check whether size moderates the impact of COVID-19 on income. However, I cannot model the data.
Do I need to create a COVID-19 dummy and stack all the on top of one another and take COVID dummy as the independent variable and income as dependent variable?

[image]